# passing argument to Runtime.getRuntime().exec() with an option at the beginning

Tags: java, unix, environment-variables, runtime.exec

I'm trying to pass a command like the following to Runtime.getRuntime().exec() where the option should be at the beginning.

```
option="something" ./test.sh a b
```

Whatever I'm trying, I get this exception:

```
Cannot run program "option="something"": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `option="something"` only works in shells to set an environment variable for this specific process. To do this in java you must use one of the overloads of `exec` that take environment variables as a parameter.

Such as:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[])

or use ProcessBuilder:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Edit:

You should note that explicitly setting environment variables for the new process, causes all environment variables in the current program to be ignored. If you want to pass the current environment variables you must include them yourself.